# How to migrate default values and constraints of a shapefile to layers created in PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have completed my project using shapefiles. But it took time to render when viewing the data so I uploaded those data in PostGIS database. Is there a way to migrate all the default values and constraints of the shapefile to the layers I created in PostGIS database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to apply the layer style to your layer stored in PostGIS, then right click on that layer -> "Export layer" -> "Save layer style" -> "Save in database" and then set default style.

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped ! :)